# Como fazer paginação dentro de um modal em bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal, paginação

Tenho um modal em bootstrap que é aberto ao clicar um botão, dentro desse modal quero exibir 2 conteúdos: 1 formulário e 1 parágrafo. Entretanto, gostaria de paginar isso dentro do modal, 1 pagina o formulário e na outra o paragrafo. Alguém tem alguma luz?

Olhei na documentação no Bootstrap mas nada que solucionasse.

Comment: já tentou fazer com guias?

Answer (score 1):

Já experimentou usar o componente TABs do próprio bootstrap?
[Bootstrap TAB](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)